# What is the better approach to update state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new in React/Redux. Plese help me to figure out what is the better approach to update state in redux?
I can call a bunch of actions and manage state in many cases of my reducer or 
I can manage state in react component and call only one action to update state in only one case of reducer.

```
// Option #1
const reducer = (state = {items: [], counter: 0, someAnotherData: {}}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_ITEM: {
            const updatedItems = state.items.concat(action.payload);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: updatedItems});
        }
        case REMOVE_ITEM: {
            const updatedItems = state.items.filter(e => e.id !== action.payload);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: updatedItems});
        }
    }
    // cases for counter and someAnotherData
};

// component
render() {
    // ...
    <Button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: item})}>
        Add
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'REMOVE_ITEM', payload: id})}>
        Remove
    </Button>
    {...}
}

// Option #2
const reducer = (state = {items: [], counter: 0, someAnotherData: {}}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_DATA':
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
        // no more cases
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

// component
addItem = (item) => {
    const updatedItems = this.props.items.concat(item);
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_DATA', payload: {items: updatedItems}});
}

removeItem = (id) => {
    const updatedItems = this.props.items.filter(e => e.id !== id);
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_DATA', payload: {items: updatedItems}});
}

render() {
    // ...
    <Button onClick={() => this.addItem(item)}>
        ADD
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={() => this.removeItem(id)}>
    REMOVE
    </Button>
    {...}
}
```

For me option #2 seems better as I can see what is going on in the same file, but I'm not sure that this is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use `ActionCreators` as follows:

```
function mapActionsToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actionCreator1: () => dispatch(updateDataAC())
    };
}
```

pass this as second param while connecting your component to store as follows:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(ComponentName);
```

Then in your component you can make use of prop actionCreator1 to invoke the action creator : addItemAC which has following definition in some configuration file:

```
export const addItemAC = () => ({
    type: 'ADD_ITEM'
});
```

That basically helps you keep your code clean and more organised.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should explain my issue better. I mean where should I but the logic of adding / removing / etc data: in a reducer or in a react component? In the second option I'm handling only one action "UPDATE_DATA" (yeah, you're right, the same I can achieve with ActionCreators) and adding / removing data in my react component. Does this approach have pitfalls?

Comment: You should manipulate store contents in reducer and not in react component as you may want to reuse the same logic in multiple places. Hence better to keep it independent of a component.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the best practice from [Redux's official document](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html).

Simply put, we will use `Actions` and `ActionCreators` to encapsulate all complexity of `Store` data change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should explain my issue better. I mean where should I but the logic of adding / removing / etc data: in a reducer or in a react component? In the second option I'm handling only one action "UPDATE_DATA" (yeah, you're right, the same I can achieve with ActionCreators) and adding / removing data in my react component. Does this approach have pitfalls?